# Высчитать сколько процентов занимает 1 пункт из общего числа

Tags: php

Есть массив, в котором записаны цифры. В массиве много элементов, но вывожу я только 10.

Делаю так:

```
$mp=0; 
foreach ($newIDs2 as $key => $value) { 
    $mp++;
    if ($mp <= 10) {
       //вывожу число ($value)
    }
}
```

На выходе получаю так:

```
5
5
5
и т.д.
```

То есть получается что каждое число занимает **33.3%**

Как на выходе получить такое:

```
5 - 33.3
5 - 33.3
5 - 33.3
```

Но чтобы считало % правильно, так как значения не всегда будут = 5, они всегда разные

Comment: от чего процент считать? я не понял

Comment: Школьная математика же, просто поделить на сумму чисел

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько из суммы всех 10 элементов массива, наверное...

Comment: @andreymal можно пример?

Comment: @Денис перебирать все числа в цикле вы уже умеете, складывать в переменную тоже, деление вообще элементарно. Какой пример нужен-то?

Comment: @andreymal как считать я знаю. 100*на первое значение/сумму оставшихся значений. не понятно как в массиве получить сумму оставшихся значений

Comment: Сделайте два цикла, в первом посчитайте сумму нужных чисел, а во втором цикле используйте заранее посчитанную сумму для подсчёта процентов

Comment: @Денис, от чего процент считать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если найти процент от всех чисел, то :

```
$mp = 0; 
$data = [];
$sum = 0;

foreach ($newIDs2 as $key => $value)
{ 
    if ($mp < 10) {
        $data[] = $value;
    }

    $sum += $value;
    $mp++;
}

foreach($data as $value) {
    echo $value.' - '.round(($value / $sum * 100), 2).'%'. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Вариант 2

```
$sum = array_sum($newIDs2);

$length = count($newIDs2);
if($length>10){
   $length = 10;
}

for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    echo newIDs2[$i].' - '.round((newIDs2[$i] / $sum * 100), 2).'%'. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Первый цикл можно сократить до ``$sum = array_sum(array_slice($newIDs2, 0, 10));``

Comment: @Эникейщик если нужна сумма всего массива, то что вы сокращаете?

Comment: Сокращаю 7 строчек (не считая пустой) и улучшаю читабельность. А если нужна сумма всего массива, то ``$sum = array_sum($my_array);``.

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил этот вариант тоже